# Is it possible to change default sharepoint 2013 app url

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

The default app url looks like http://[app prefix]-[app id].[domain name]/[site collection path]/[app path]/pages/default.aspx.
It is unconvinient because every deployment during development generates new url. And after development stage the end users need a permanent link to the application, but every bug fixes or updates that will be deployed will cause new app url generation. Is there right way to fix the app url?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a URL controller:

Create a list that would contain two fields: **fakeUrl, realUrl,**

**fakeUrl** can be something like "http://staticappname.[domain name]/[site collection path]/[app path]/pages/default.aspx"

**realUrl** would be your http://[app prefix]-[app id].[domain name]/[site collection path]/[app path]/pages/default.aspx

Give your users **fakeUrl**

Create a HTTPModule that would read the list and redirect the http request to the **realUrl**

After you redeploy your app, just change the **realUrl** in the list

***I'm not if this is your case but you could change your app to be a provider-hosted. Then you would get a static Url

Answer (score 0):

You can open your SharePoint hosted add-in using an alternate link like:

```
http://[SharePointSite]/[Add-inName]
```

For eg.

```
http://contoso.com/sharepointhostedapp/
```